# Where to force xilinx ISE to use block-rams?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I synthesized a small device to test the block-ram inference.

I got a message from XST :

> The small RAM  will be
>   implemented on LUTs in order to
>   maximize performance and save block
>   RAM resources. If you want to force
>   its implementation on block, use
>   **option/constraint ram_style**.

However, I don't know where to find this option/constraint either in ISE (11.1 in my case) or in constraint files...

I don't want to use VHDL attributes directly in my code.

Comment: run -ram_style BLOCK can do the trick in command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your project directory, you'll find a file called "your-design.xst". You can add the following at the end of the list (or anywhere after "run"):

```
-ram_style block # ( | auto | distributed )
-rom_style block # ( | auto | distributed )
```

These should make sure you're going to get BRAM mapping instead of distributed RAM (which means LUT-based memory).

This option could also come in handy:

```
-auto_bram_packing yes # ( | no )
```

Remember that each of those must be on a line of their own, and that you'll need to remove the "#" and whatever comes after that.

If you're using the ISE GUI, go to

```
Synthesis -> Process Properties -> HDL options
```

and choose the above options there.

(BTW, we're trying to start an SE site dedicated to FPGAs... consider supporting it... http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20632/programmable-logic-and-fpga-design?referrer=YmxhQ2OJUo-FAaI1gMp5oQ2)

Answer (score 2):

run -ram_style BLOCK can do the trick in command line.